# Organization, Application. Orderer. Channel in config file. How to design it?

Tags: hyperledger, policy

The configtx.yml has different parts and their let's say book definitions:

**Organizations** - This section defines the different organizational identities which will be referenced later in the configuration.
**Application** - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or genesis block for application related parameters.
**Orderer** - defines the values to encode into a config transaction or genesis block for orderer related parameters
**Channel** - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or genesis block for channel related parameters.
**Profile** - comes in the end.

How do you understand this file to create a logic ?

For example:
We have an ordererorg, org1 and org2.

ordererorg has org1msp and org2msp.

org 1 endorses org2 transaction.
org 2 endorses org 1 transaction.

both orgs have 1 peer each. both orgs have 1 admin each.

I do not know what is the meaning of org 1 having an org 1 client and member? what does they represent?

So how should the file be designed, meaning what is the idea for organization section? followed by application and so on? I hope you get the confusion and purpose of my question.

Answer (score 0):

The design depends on the use case. In fabric, the config file is basically a setup file where you can define all the Organizations, Policies, Capabilities, etc.

As per your requirement, you can create n number of Orderes, Peers and You can define the channel setup. Also, you can have n number of peers/orderes under an organization. There can be one admin, one peer, and one client for an organization.

To understand each concept, go through the official documentation.